# How to create angular2 form with editable mode and view mode?

Tags: angular

I want to create an angular2 form with 2 modes, editable and view mode.

In editable mode we can add data or edit data, however I view mode we just view the data in form view.

any idea on how to do it?

Comment: one way and two way binding

Comment: what it mean ?
can you explain more please.

Comment: look up angular2 and two way binding.  there are several sites that will give you a tutorial on how to make an editable field.  Your question is very broad, so i cannot get more specific than that with out seeing code you've written

Answer (score 0):

> You can put disabled tag on each input with some condition  if
>   isEditable varible is true in TS (controller) file only then you would
>   be able to change or edit input

```
[disabled]="!isEditable"
```

like

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!personForm.form.valid">Save</button>
```

Comment: yes this is valid method,but i think this method is inefficient, i just wonder is there any method that can do it in the form level not input level

Comment: You can do with *ngif  like 
<div *ngIf="isEdit">your form </div>
<div *ngIf="!isEdit">Only view part may in p tag instead of input</div>